# How to INSERT rows based on other rows?

Tags: sql-server

I need to run a query that will `INSERT` new rows into a SQL Server `join` table.

Suppose I have the following tables to describe which products a store sells and in which states:

**`products`:**

```
+------------+--------------+
| product_id | product_name |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | Laptop       |
|          2 | Aspirin      |
|          3 | Mattress     |
+------------+--------------+
```

**`stores`:**

```
+----------+------------+
| store_id | store_name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | Walmart    |
|        2 | Best Buy   |
|        3 | Sam's Club |
+----------+------------+
```

**`products_stores_states`:**

```
+------------+----------+-------+
| product_id | store_id | state |
+------------+----------+-------+
|          1 |        2 | AL    |
|          1 |        2 | AR    |
|          2 |        2 | AL    |
|          2 |        2 | AR    |
|          3 |        2 | AL    |
|          3 |        2 | AR    |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

So here we see that Best Buy sells all 3 products in AL and AR.

What I need to do is somehow insert rows into the `products_stores_states` table to add AZ for all products it currently sells.

With a small dataset, I could do this manually, row by row:

```
INSERT INTO products_stores_states (product_id, store_id, state) VALUES
    (1,2,'AZ'),
    (2,2,'AZ'),
    (3,2,'AZ');
```

Since this is a large dataset, this is not really an option.

How would I go about inserting a new state for Best Buy for every `product_id` that the `products_stores_states` table already contains for Best Buy?

> **Bonus:** If a query could be made to do this for multiple states that the same time, that would be even better.

Right now, I cannot wrap my head around how to do this, but I assume there would need to be a subquery to get the list of matching `product_id` values I need to use.

Comment: You mean, by using a `SELECT` and a `JOIN` (like in this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#y-using-a-label-and-a-query-hint-with-the-insert-statement))?

Comment: Are you going to relate these with FK's after? Where is the states coming from or does everyone get AZ?

Comment: @scsimon the `product_id` and `store_id` are linked by FK currently, yes.

Comment: @Larnu Possible? I'm afraid I'm pretty novice to SQL Server syntax, so I'm not quite sure I understand exactly what that example is doing. At least as far as the `JOIN` portion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are positive the inserted state is "NEW" to the table, something like this would work, changing the state variable to whatever you want to insert the new records.

```
DECLARE @State CHAR(2), @StoreId INT;
SET @State = 'AZ';
SET @StoreId = 2;

INSERT INTO products_stores_states (product_id, store_id, state)
SELECT DISTINCT product_id, @StoreId, @State
FROM dbo.products_stores_states
WHERE store_id = @StoreId;
```

You could first see what this statement would add using this:

```
DECLARE @State CHAR(2)
SET @State = 'AZ';
SET @StoreId = 2;

SELECT DISTINCT product_id, @StoreId, @State
FROM dbo.products_stores_states
WHERE store_id = @StoreId;
```

Comment: What is the danger if the state **does** exist in the table, for some reason? It would just fail the unique constraint, yes, since the entire row would already exist?

Comment: I did not see mention of the products_stores_states table having a unique constraint, yes the insert statement would just fail. If the table did not have the constraint, you'd have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will do what you want to do

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
 state VARCHAR(20)
)

-- we are inserting state names into a temp table to use it further 
INSERT INTO @temp (state)
VALUES
('AZ'),
('MA'),
('TX');

INSERT INTO products_stores_states(product_id, store_id, state )
SELECT
  T.product_id,
  T.store_id,
  temp.state
FROM(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    Product_id, store_id
  FROM
    products_stores_states
  WHERE store_id = 2 -- the store_id for which you want to make changes
) AS T
CROSS JOIN
 @temp AS temp
```

At first, we are storing the state names into a table variable. Then we need to select only the **distinct** `store_id` and `product_id` combinations for a **specific store**.

Then we should insert the distinct values `cross join` with the table variable where we stored state names.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cee1c682dc96685e31e9f7e0e21fc76f) is the live demo.

Hope, this helps! Thanks.